# Output Method Return Value to Variable? Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to store the output of a method in a variable in Ruby? For example, if I wanted to store the return value of display_results in a variable to be evaluated by win_counter is that possible? I want win_counter to increment every time display_results has a winner.

```
win_combos = [
  ['rock', 'scissors'],
  ['paper', 'rock'],
  ['scissors', 'paper'],
  ['rock', 'lizard'],
  ['lizard', 'spock'],
  ['spock', 'scissors'],
  ['scissors', 'lizard'],
  ['lizard', 'paper'],
  ['paper', 'spock'],
  ['spock', 'rock']
]

scores = { player: 0, computer: 0 }

def display_results(first, second, combos = [])  
  combos.each do |combo|
    if combo == [first, second]
      puts "Player won!"
      break
    elsif combo == [second, first]
      puts "Computer won!"
      break
    end
  end
  if first == second
    puts "It's a tie!"
  end
end

def win_counter(player, computer, scores)
  if display_results(player, computer)
    scores[:player] = scores[:player] + 1
  elsif display_results(computer, player)
    scores[:computer] = scores[:computer] + 1
  end
  puts "players wins: #{scores[:player]}; computer wins: #{scores[:computer]}"
end

display_results('spock', 'rock', win_combos)
win_counter('spock', 'rock', scores)
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set a variable equal to the method call.  You could use:

```
if display_results(player, computer) == "Player won!"
```

However, it might be more useful to split the logic for printing the winner away from the logic for the actual game. In ruby methods that return booleans are stylized with a '?' i.e empty? display_results should only display the results of the game, you shouldn't use an if statement on it.